# Using lookup table vs. values for 'else' case when the list of possibilities is not defined

Tags: sql, database

I am trying to design a lookup table, but I do not know how to design storage for values that do not match.

Example: for lookup values 'A', 'B' and 'C' I want lookup value 1, but for all the others (and the list is not defined) I want a value -1.

using case I would have written

```
CASE 
WHEN VALUE IN('A','B','C') THEN 1
ELSE -1
END
```

But how to do the same using a lookup table?

Comment: It is irrelevant for the problem in my opinion, since it is a design problem.

Comment: Lookup tables work with a predefined list of values, I'm not aware of a catch-all value. Perhaps a view would be better solution (left join on the lookup table, replace null values with -1).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `left join`:

```
SELECT t.*,
       COALESCE(v.result, -1)
FROM t LEFT JOIN
     (VALUES ('A', 1), ('B', 1), ('C', 1)) v(value, result)
     ON t.value = v.value;
```

You can include a default value as well, say using `NULL`:

```
WITH reference AS (
      SELECT *
      FROM (VALUES ('A', 1), ('B', 1), ('C', 1), (NULL, -1)
           ) v(value, result)
     )
SELECT t.*,
       COALESCE(r.result, r_default.result) as result
FROM t LEFT JOIN
     reference r
     ON r.value = t.value LEFT JOIN
     reference r_default
     ON r_default.value IS NULL;
```

Comment: thank you very much, that is what i was looking for